# sorl-thumbnail not displaying image in Django Template

Tags: python, django, sorl-thumbnail

**models.py**:

```
class NewImage(models.Model):
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos')
    time_created = models.DateTimeField()
```

**forms.py**:

```
class ImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = NewImage
        fields = {'thumbnail'}
```

I have rendered this form in my template and the pictures gets uploaded successfully. I also get them displayed without `sorl-thumbnail`.

**views.py**:

```
def loadImages(request):
    images = NewImage.objects.all()
    context = {'images': images}
    return render(request, 'mysite/imagedisplay.html', context)
```

**imagedisplay.html**:

```
{% load thumbnail %}

{% for image in images %}
    <p>{{image.time_created}}</p>
    <img src='..{{image.thumbnail.url}}' width = '50%'/>
{% endfor %}
 <!-- this displays the images but the code below doesn't work -->
{% for image in images %}
    {% thumbnail image.thumbnail "100x100" crop="center" as im %}
        <img src="{{ im.url }}" width="{{ im.width }}" height="{{ im.height }}">
    {% endthumbnail %}
{% endfor %}
```

It only display square box without the image:
[image]

When I inspect the box to see the source it shows `<img src="/mediafiles/cache/e0/b4/e0b4ff0750a34c5c417b30058554c160.jpg" width="100" height="100">`

instead of `<img src="../mediafiles/photos/170_kclgRCl.jpg" width="100" height="100">`

How do I get this work?

Comment: did you clear the cache?

Comment: I don't know how to do that.

Comment: just delete the cache folder and you are all set. sorl will generate the file for you. !

Comment: @Yax you got it work?

Comment: @rajasimon: I have deleted the cache file but it is still not working...

Comment: ok seems looking good to me.. One thing is tell how you installed sorl ?

Comment: I `pip install sorl-thumbnail`. I deleted the cache folder, uploaded another image and another cache folder was created with image buried there `cache/7a/16/image003443538989234a.jpg`. But it is still not working.

Comment: did you forgot the syncdb...?